# Application interface font colour often light gray on bright colours

Tags: fonts, interface

I often encounter bright font colours on bright backgrounds in some applications, such as the Cisco Packet Tracer or dark colours on dark backgrounds, e.g. in Anki.

[image: Image describing the interface problem]

How can I change the interface font colour, even if the app itself does not give that possibility?

Thank you